# creating file using install with preset user and group

Tags: bash, installation, centos7

Trying to create a file with preset user and users group

missing destination file operand after

```
install -m 644 -o root -g root /var/test/file
```

getting an error:

```
install: missing destination file operand after ‘/var/test/file’
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

Note: does work fine for directory creation, with -d but not for files...

Answer (score 1):

`install` needs a destination operand when used with a file. If you want to install `/var/test/file` in the current directory, use:

`install -m 644 -o root -g root /var/test/file .`

Comment: If you mean to put a dot in the end it gives an other error:  install -m 644 -o root -g root /var/test/file .
install: cannot stat ‘/var/test/file’: No such file or directory

Comment: After reading documentation, it seems install can't really create files like touch does, it is build mostly to copy files from place to place preserving characteristics .....

Comment: `install` will copy a file and adjust its permissions, user and group if needed. If the file you want to install does not exist, it won't work. If `/var/test/file` is your destination, then you need to insert a source file before in the commande line: `install -m 644 -o root -g root /my/original/file /var/test/file`

Comment: thanks, yes I've got that, I was hoping install can create, not copy files as it successfully does with directories.